# Conditional Chunk based on Template used in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, templates, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to evaluate a chunk in `Rmarkdown`document based on the template being used. If the template file is `abc.tex` then the chunk should evaluate else not. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rmarkdown::metadata`, which gives you the Meta/YAML data of the document thats currently processed:

````
```{r include = F}
cond.eval <- rmarkdown::metadata$output$pdf_document$template == 'abc.tex' 
``` 


```{r eval = cond.eval}
print('Yes')
```
````

If you are using **shared YAML options** you can try

````
```{r include=F}
meta      <- yaml::yaml.load_file(paste0(getwd(), '/_output.yaml'))
cond.eval <- meta$pdf_document$template == 'abc.tex'
``` 


```{r eval = cond.eval}
print('Yes')
```
````

Comment: I am using a separate `_output.yml` so maybe that is the reason I don't have `output` in `rmarkdown::metadata`.